# Which Artificer Infusions are appropriate for the Armorer's Arcane Armor's special weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

At 9th level, the Armorer Artificer (from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything) gains the "Armor Modifications" feature :

> You learn how to use your artificer infusions to specially modify your Arcane Armor. That armor now counts as separate items for the purposes of your Infuse Items feature: armor (the chest piece), boots, helmet, **and the armor’s special weapon**. Each of those items can bear one of your infusions, and the infusions transfer over if you change your armor’s model with the Armor Model feature. In addition, the maximum number of items you can infuse at once increases by 2, but those extra items must be part of your Arcane Armor.

This special weapon is called 'Thunder Gauntlets' (a simple melee weapon) for the 'Guardian' Armor Model, and 'Lightning Launcher' (a simple ranged weapon) for the 'Infiltrator' Model.

But I am wondering which Artificer Infusions are appropriate for this special weapon ? Is it only the 'Enhanced Weapon' and 'Radiant Weapon' infusions, or are there others ?

Answer (score 2):

#### Yes, only Radiant Weapon and Enhanced Weapon

Taking a look on the infusions that are on *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* Enhanced Weapon and Radiant Weapon are the only ones that could be applied  in the armor's special weapon, since others infusions that can be applied on weapons, such as *Repeating Shot* and *Returning Weapon* have others restrictions that neither forms of the special weapon complies (have the ammunition property in the case of repeating shot and the throw property in the case of returning weapon).

Comment: @Makrau You can use Returning Weapon on thunder gauntlets that are affected by the Arcane Propulsion armor infusion on your armor's chestpiece, although their is no benefit for doing so over just using the enhanced weapon infusion